# Declaring global pointer to structs

Tags: go

I want to declare a pointer to a struct globally so that I can access this pointer in other files within my package. How do I do that?

Details:
Package Y has struct named "Cluster" and also some functions named NewCluster etc.

```
type Cluster struct {
}
func NewCluster(self *Node, credentials Credentials) *Cluster {
    return &Cluster{
    }
}
```

---

Now,from package "X" when I tried accessing above cluster as below, it works good

cluster := Y.NewCluster(node, credentials)

Now, I want to declare this 'cluster' as a global variable so that I can access it in other files of my "X" package. So, I am trying to declare it many ways but its not working. How do I declare it globally? and then how do I access it in other files of my "X"package or else in the same file (to invoke same NewCluster function)?

Edit: 
I tried declaring as var cluster Cluster, var *cluster Cluster , var cluster *Cluster etc. but nothing works.

Comment: `var cluster *Cluster` --- what's wrong with this one?

Comment: It says undefined: Cluster

Comment: in package X, use `var cluster *Y.Cluster`.

Comment: @zzn That works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or
>   function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function)
>   is the package block.

[Go Language Specification: Scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

So a variable declared in one package file outside of a function should be available in any other package file.

I think all you're missing here is the package name for the Cluster type: you need a qualified identifier.

> A qualified identifier is an identifier qualified with a package name
>   prefix. Both the package name and the identifier must not be blank.

[Go Language Specification: Qualified Identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers)

The type Cluster is defined in package Y, as is the function NewCluster.  When you accessed NewCluster from package X, you used a qualified identifier by prefixing the function name with the package name and a dot:

```
cluster := Y.NewCluster(node, credentials)
```

When you're trying to reference a type in package Y from package X, you need to do it with a qualified identifier.  For example:

```
var cluster *Y.Cluster
```